# How to pass variable from jsf managed bean to jsp page

Tags: jsp, session, jsf, liferay, portal

How can I pass a variable from JSF managed bean to JSP page.

PS: I'm in portal context (liferay).

I tried this:

in Managed Bean:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

request.setAttribute("var", "someTxt");
```

in JSP:

```
<% 
    String var = (String)request.getAttribute("var");
%>
```

I don't get any result.

Comment: show us how you "move" from the managed bean to the jsp - redirect, forward, navigation rule (what does it look like)

Comment: Why don't you just set it as a JSF bean property and acces it in JSP the usual EL way?

Comment: Thank you BalusC,

the jsf application is a portlet, and the jsp page is in another portlet writing in jsp tags no jsf, it's a lifray portlet.

I also see a your post in your blog about "Communication in JSF", for my case it's between a jsp page of liferay and jsf managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stay in the same request - i.e. forward, instead of redirect to the jsp.

If this is not possible you may use the session instead of the request, but be careful with storing too much information there.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to wrap your scriptlet code with  JSF tag.